# ERROR: HHH000346: Caused by org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException and java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am learning Hibernate as a beginner,I am working with maven + hibernate + oracle11g

I am receiving error when i run the following code
Here is the code which i am working on :

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.wipro.HibernateDemp</groupId>
  <artifactId>HibernateDemo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>HibernateDemo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
 
  <dependencies>
  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc6 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
  </dependencies>
  
</project>
```

Department.java

```
package com.hibernate.bean;

import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Department 
{
    private int depno;
    private String depName;
    private int locationid;
    private int managerid;
    
    public Department() {
        
    }
    
    public Department(int depno, String depName, int locationid, int managerid) {
        super();
        this.depno = depno;
        this.depName = depName;
        this.locationid = locationid;
        this.managerid = managerid;
    }
    
    
    public int getDepno() {
        return depno;
    }

    public void setDepno(int depno) {
        this.depno = depno;
    }


    public String getDepName() {
        return depName;
    }

    public void setDepName(String depName) {
        this.depName = depName;
    }

    public int getLocationid() {
        return locationid;
    }


    public void setLocationid(int locationid) {
        this.locationid = locationid;
    }


    public int getManagerid() {
        return managerid;
    }

    public void setManagerid(int managerid) {
        this.managerid = managerid;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Department [depno=" + depno + ", depName=" + depName + ", locationid=" + locationid + ", managerid="
                + managerid + "]";
    }
    
    
}
```

DepartmentAdmin.java

```
package com.wipro.services;

import javax.transaction.Transaction;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.hibernate.bean.Department;

public class DepartmentAdmin {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();
        SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session =sf.openSession();
        org.hibernate.Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Department deptobj = new Department(280,"CSE", 116,1830);
        session.save(deptobj);
        transaction.commit();
        System.out.println("Record inserted");
        System.out.println(deptobj);
        session.close();
    }

}
```

department.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping 
PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.wipro.bean.Department" table="Departments">
<id name="depno" column="DEPARTMENT_ID" type="int">
    <generator class="assigned"></generator>
</id>
<property name="depName" column="DEPARTMENT_NAME" type="string"></property>
<property name="locationid" column="LOCATION_ID" type="int"></property>
<property name="managerid" column="MANAGER_ID" type="int"></property>

</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">hr</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">hr</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect</property>
<property name="hibernateshow_sql">true</property>


<mapping resource="department.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am receiving the following when i run the code:

```
May 28, 2022 11:58:17 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.11.Final}
May 28, 2022 11:58:17 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
May 28, 2022 11:58:17 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
May 28, 2022 11:58:17 AM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
May 28, 2022 11:58:17 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
May 28, 2022 11:58:17 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe]
May 28, 2022 11:58:17 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=hr}
May 28, 2022 11:58:17 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
May 28, 2022 11:58:17 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
May 28, 2022 11:58:18 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect
May 28, 2022 11:58:18 AM org.hibernate.search.engine.Version <clinit>
INFO: HSEARCH000034: Hibernate Search 5.8.0.Final
May 28, 2022 11:58:18 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 2291, SQLState: 23000
May 28, 2022 11:58:18 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (HR.DEPT_MGR_FK) violated - parent key not found

May 28, 2022 11:58:18 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
May 28, 2022 11:58:18 AM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1443)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3207)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2413)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at com.wipro.services.DepartmentAdmin.main(DepartmentAdmin.java:19)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3013)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3513)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:589)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (HR.DEPT_MGR_FK) violated - parent key not found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3694)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 18 more
```

Table departments structure:

```
Name            | Null?    |  Type         |
:---------------|:--------:| ------------ :|
DEPARTMENT_ID   | NOT NULL | NUMBER(4)     |
DEPARTMENT_NAME | NOT NULL |VARCHAR2(30)   |
MANAGER_ID      |          |NUMBER(6)      |
LOCATION_ID     |          | NUMBER(4)     |
```

I have no idea what is happening here...anyhelp is most welcomed...

Comment: the database is complaining that some foreign key is not found - did you create the tables to access somehow before? Your beans have to reflect the complete structure of the tables, you cannot just work with some of the fields in the tables. Hibernate is an O/R mapper, that means it maps objects to a relational database _and_ vice versa. The mapping has to be complete. Can you add the structure of your table to the question please`?

Comment: Yes I created the table earlier... I've added the structure to the question.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no leftovers from previous examples you tried? Oracles error message is that you would violate a constraint (HR.DEPT_MGR_FK) that looks like if you were linking the MANAGER_ID as foreign key to another table. Please ensure that no such foreign key relation is set up in your database.

Comment: yea I had it...but now I created a new table without any foreign key relation...yet I still get the same error.

Comment: Foreign key relations could be leftovers from before. try to recreate the whole database or create a new database and connect to that. You chose not the simplest initial setup for learning O/R mapping - I would have recommended JPA2 with Hibernate to start with, but maybe that's not challenging enough for you ;) You have to learn the database internals as well in O/R-mapping to do it good, and Oracle has just a _high_ complexity among relational databases.

Comment: Okay sure...I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't map the association correctly. Given the name of the table and constraint, I think there's not a manager matching the id you have specified.

A relationship between Department and Manager (assuming a department has only one manager) should look something like:

```
@Entity
public class Department {

    ....

    @ManyToOne // Assuming a manager can manage multiple departments
    Manager manager;
}

@Entity
public class Manager {
   // ... id, fields, getters/setters
}
```

I've used annotations because I find it easier (and probably more common) but you can do the same with XML.

I would suggest to check the [Hibernate ORM documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-one) to figure out how to map associations.